# Not to able to connect from superset to druid

Tags: docker, apache-superset, druid

I am trying to connect from a superset running on docker-compose to my druid cluster (running in 1 master, 1 historical, 1 mm and 1 query)
I followed the instructions here https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/operations/security-overview.html to setup the basic auth, No TLS though
and I have tried both druid coordinator and druid broker at 9088, 8082 etc but keep getting
superset.exceptions.SupersetTimeoutException: Please check your connection details and database settings, and ensure that your database is accepting connections, then try connecting again.
is there in anything to do in the docker-compose.yml or anywhere else. Pls guide as I dont know what exactly is missing
I also see func_timeout.exceptions.FunctionTimedOut: Function ping (args=(Engine(druid://admin:***@brokerhost:8082/druid/v2/sql),)) (kwargs={}) timed out after 30.000000 seconds.
on docker console (new to docker as well)
so I tried to curl from the superset_app container but it's not reaching . All running on EC2 and I have the ports opened as well in my security group for the container IP (edited)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: I can get the ip address of my docker container
using
ifconfig | grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | cut -f2 -d: | head -n1
and I have added the ip to the AWS SG outbound rules for port 8082 and 9088, along with the host machine ip, still when I do curl to the ip inside docker shell
(
docker ps
docker exec -it superset_app /bin/bash
) its not able to reach the druid master or broker

Comment: Druid cluster is also set up through docker-compose, or it's running on your local host, not from container? Can you add docker-compose.yml for superset app to your post?

Answer (score 2):

Solved, I added the druid security group to the superset instance and now it's able to connect. I think I meesed up in the superset SG, will need to clean it up